# Problem with shooting. Projectile is missing target from about 5 degrees to about 30 degrees

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to make projectile shooting code. But there is a problem, in most cases projectile is missing target.

-sprite is origin of projectile 
-bulletSprite is a projectile
-mouse is a target

```
float moveX, moveY;

void getTarget(){

float directionX = sf::Mouse::getPosition().x - sprite.getPosition().x;
float directionY = sf::Mouse::getPosition().y - sprite.getPosition().y;

float magnitude = sqrt((directionX*directionX) + (directionY*directionY));

moveX = directionX / magnitude;
moveY = directionY / magnitude;

bulletSprite.setPosition(sprite.getPosition());}

void fire(){
bulletSprite.move(sf::Vector2f(moveX, moveY));}
```

Looks like changing float to long double helps a bit.
Gif with this problem - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxPqUosXueuNY2FjcmluWlBZWW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or GIF of the bullet and sprite in the question?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxPqUosXueuNY2FjcmluWlBZWW8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know anything about `sf::Mouse::getPosition()`, but are you sure the coordinates are _relative_ to the canvas? To ensure this, you can subtract the coordinates of the canvas from the coordinates of the mouse. Also, make sure they are relative to the window.

Comment: getPosition takes window as parameter, if it is not passed then it returns global mouse position

Comment: Thanks. I changed sf::Mouse::getPosition() to sf::Mouse::getPosition(window) and its working now. Also found this on sfml site https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Mouse.php#ac368680f797b7f6e4f50b5b7928c1387